# Android Get Current timestamp?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timestamp, epoch

I want to get the current timestamp like that : **1320917972**

```
int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());
Timestamp tsTemp = new Timestamp(time);
String ts =  tsTemp.toString();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `Timestamp` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 357, accepted):

The solution is :

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
String ts = tsLong.toString();
```

Comment: This doesn't factor in the timezone offset of the device.

Comment: @kjdion84 excuse me, but why do you think it would be important ? Just based on the question.

Comment: Is there a way to get this as `int`?

Answer (score 89):

From developers blog:

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is the standard "wall" clock (time and date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network (see [setCurrentTimeMillis(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#setCurrentTimeMillis%28long%29)), so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application. Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock. If you are using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, consider listening to the `ACTION_TIME_TICK`, `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and `ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED` Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29  I found that `System.nanoTime()` is an alternative to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and it has no unpredictable fluctuations, and is designed for measuring duration differences.

Comment: @ana01 "the zero value is typically whenever the device last booted" - so it can be used only when you compare duration differences on the same device. Not useful for database storage for example.

Comment: Just a note to @ana01 's comment  that `System.nanoTime()` isn't suitable for to display wall clock time. For that purpose, use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead.

Answer (score 40):

**1320917972** is Unix timestamp using number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970. You can use `TimeUnit` class for unit conversion - from `System.currentTimeMillis()` to seconds.

```
String timeStamp = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
```

Comment: This is not a timestamp (time since epoch)

Comment: Not a timestamp, and moreover, not efficiant at all (creation of SimpleDateFormat, creation of date, conversion). Avoid it.

Comment: You are answering sth else, but it's also valid.

Answer (score 24):

Use below method to get current time stamp. It works fine for me.

```
/**
 * 
 * @return yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss formate date as string
 */
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp(){
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date

        return currentDateTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a timestamp.

Comment: @Hits, It's Simple Date Format, not a timestamp. You are just using variable name as currentTimeStap.

Answer (score 13):

It's simple use:

```
long millis = new Date().getTime();
```

if you want it in particular format then you need Formatter like below

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String millisInString  = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: This gives GMT time.

Answer (score 10):

***Nov 2023***
Here is the comparison list of the most widely known methods

| fun | accuracy | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| System.nanoTime() | Precise | **High-resolution** the current value of the running Java Virtual Machines time source, in nanoseconds. |
| System.currentTimeMillis() | High | **Very efficient** the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. |
| Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() | High | **Low efficiency** the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch. |
| new Date().getTime() | High | **Low efficiency** the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this date. |
| Instant.now().getEpochSecond() | Medium | **Requires Api 26** the seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. |
| Clock.System.now() | High | **Kotlin** |

Answer (score 9):

You can get Current timestamp in Android by trying below code

```
time.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

and timeStamp to time format

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(time.getText().toString())));
time.setText(dateString);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a human-readable time stamp that may be used in a file name,
just in case someone needs the same thing that I needed:

```
package com.example.xyz;

import android.text.format.Time;

/**
 * Clock utility.
 */
public class Clock {

    /**
     * Get current time in human-readable form.
     * @return current time as a string.
     */
    public static String getNow() {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String sTime = now.format("%Y_%m_%d %T");
        return sTime;
    }
    /**
     * Get current time in human-readable form without spaces and special characters.
     * The returned value may be used to compose a file name.
     * @return current time as a string.
     */
    public static String getTimeStamp() {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String sTime = now.format("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S");
        return sTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, Could u also tell the best way to sort a list of timestamps? I was thinking of sorting them myself but thought there may be a better way.

Comment: For future reference for anybody reading this be aware that "android.text.format.Time" is now deprecated

Answer (score 8):

Solution in Kotlin:

```
val nowInEpoch = Instant.now().epochSecond
```

Make sure your minimum SDK version is 26.

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

I should like to contribute the modern answer.

```
    String ts = String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
    System.out.println(ts);
```

Output when running just now:

> 1543320466

While division by 1000 won’t come as a surprise to many, doing your own time conversions can get hard to read pretty fast, so it’s a bad habit to get into when you can avoid it.

The `Instant` class that I am using is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s built-in on new Android versions, API level 26 and up. If you are programming for older Android, you may get the backport, see below. If you don’t want to do that, understandably, I’d still use a built-in conversion:

```
    String ts = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    System.out.println(ts);
```

This is the same as the answer by sealskej. Output is the same as before.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Almost perfect answer (I upvoted) but, at least in my honest opinion, you should remove the ThreeTen Backport reference as this is a question about Android and not Java in general. And it may get to be confusing for beginners at Android.

Comment: @SlobodanAntonijević It is important for Android programmers to understand that (a) if they are supporting Android 26 and later, they have an implementation of *java.time* built-in, (b) if supporting early Android before 26, they must add a library, the *ThreeTenABP* library, and (c) if using *ThreeTenABP*, know that this library is actually an adaptation of *ThreeTen-Backport* adapted from Java to Android. The *ThreeTenABP* library is just a Android-specific wrapper around *ThreeTen-Backport* library. See [this table graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPszD.png) comparing the 3 libraries.

Comment: @BasilBourque you are completely correct. But, you can in fact import ThreeTen-Backport and use it in an Android app, but with extremely huge impact to performance cause of its JAR dependency. This is why I've said that the post should be more specific that Android devs should never use ThreeTen-Backport, and instead use ThreeTenABP for API 25 and below support. I've seen numerous devs on various boards that get confused on which one should be used for Android, cause they sound similar by name.

Comment: Good point, @SlobodanAntonijević. I have tried to make it just a little clearer.

Comment: @SlobodanAntonijević [This table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTAlg.png) showing where to obtain *java.time* for both Java and Android might help make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Hits's answer, but adding a Locale format, this is how Android 
 Developers [recommends](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is Kotlin version. I have another idea to add a random shuffle integer in last digit for giving variance epoch time.

Kotlin version

```
val randomVariance = (0..100).shuffled().first()
val currentEpoch = (System.currentTimeMilis()/1000) + randomVariance

val deltaEpoch = oldEpoch - currentEpoch
```

I think it will be better using this kode then depend on android version 26 or more

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, this is in kotlin:

```
val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
val timeStamp = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().time)
```

Output example:

> "2022.04.22 10:22:35"

Comment: To get milliseconds just add the pattern like this: 
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")