# displaying timestamp in toast

Tags: android, timestamp, android-toast

I need to display timestamp in hh:mm format along with a toasted text. I have tried adding `+DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS` which isnt working for me

```
 Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Progress saved at"+DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        savedToast.show();
```

Edit: learnt from the answers that `+Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` does the job. Thanks. All the answers work great.

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat instead

Comment: Actually what message you got?

Comment: post code of your DateUtils class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
final int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
final int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Progress saved at"+String.valueOf(hour )+":"+String.valueOf(minute ),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    savedToast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current timestamp like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264666/4310784

then u must just show it in your toast:

```
 Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Progress saved at"+String.valueOf(tsLong),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    savedToast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");     
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String str_time = df.format(c.getTime());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Progress saved at"+str_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            DateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            Date netDate    = (new Date());
            String dateString      = sdf.format(netDate);
            Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Progress saved at " + dateString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            savedToast.show();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
```