# Save timestamp in shared preferences when a button is clicked

Tags: android, timestamp, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

How do I save a `timestamp` in shared `preferences` for the moment when a `button` is clicked?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //some logic...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to search?

Comment: Combine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077530/android-get-current-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code

```
Long timestamp = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis()
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putLong("time", timestamp).commit();
```

More details on SharedPreferences : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 1):

```
  in this way you can save current time in SharedPreferences 

  SharedPreferences preferences;
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

   preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref_namae",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putLong("TimeStamp",System.currentTimeMillis());
    editor.apply();
        }
    });

to get value from prefercance use this code.
```

long timeStamp = preferences.getLong("TimeStamp",0);

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putLong("YourKey", timestamp)
            .apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to save time in your required timestamp.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
    Date date=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String formatDate=simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

You can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#date-and-time-patterns) for other date formats. And use SharedPreference to save it.