# Store android timestamp value in millisecond without losing its precission in a string variable

Tags: java, android, time

Hi all i am trying to store android current timestamp value in a string variable without losing its precision but i am losing last 3 digits when i try to print timeStamps value. Actually its having 13 digits but only 10 digits getting printed.

```
String timeStamp = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

I got the above snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812853/5706413) I am in the process to get the recently updated contacts based on `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` for which precision seems important.Please guide me

Comment: I bet you are losing the 3 millisenconds digits. That may be due to a conversion to seconds... maybe here: `toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: You are converting it to a whole number of seconds. The string has nothing to do with the 3 digits of lost precision.

Comment: how to fix this,please guide me

Comment: Easy: don't convert it to seconds. Don't just copy/paste code but try to read the complete cited answer and try to understand what you copy

Comment: ok thanks @jhamon i shall try this... String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Comment: No :) :) Try to understand *each* peace of your code. Just `String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP) says that `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` is:

> Timestamp (milliseconds since epoch) of when this contact was last updated

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the milliseconds since epoch representing the current time.

Your primary problem is that you are converting milliseconds to seconds, which is unnecessary and incorrect for this use case.

Your secondary problem is that you are converting the value to a `String`, which AFAIK should not be necessary for this particular column.

So, just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, without any conversions.

Comment: i was converting to string to use in cursor query

Comment: @JoseKj: Ah, OK, that makes sense.